# Gradle sync failed: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0]

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I'm having the following error in my project:
11:28   Gradle sync failed: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler. (10 s 801 ms)

This is the build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.flixarts.ar.*"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.2.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
}
```

Comment: The build.gradle is updated to the last version

Answer (score 0):

Do you use **gradle version 3.x** or higher as your gradle version, and **4.x** as your **gradle-plugin**?

Project level gradle file:

```
dependencies{
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
}
```

Gradle plugin distributionUrl configuration in wrapper-properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

*or latest version of course*

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

---

### Note

you are using the problematic plugin two times in your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
```

Comment: Hi Levente How are you? I have the gradle versions exactly as you written there.

Comment: I have that plugin play-services-ads twice, once in the build.gradle Project and once in the build.gradle module app. Which line do I have to delete? (In which gradle: build.gradle Project or build.gradle Module.app)

Comment: In case you want to keep the 18.2.0, then you might need to Migrate to AndroidX (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) because the 18.0.0 has some major changes. If it's OK to you to stay on 17.2.0, then eliminate the newest version dependencies.